# pandas - make a df from all possible combinations of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['cat1', 1], ['cat2', 1], ['cat3', 2],
               ['cat1', 3]], columns=['category',
              'number'])

df
Out[32]: 
  category  number
0     cat1       1
1     cat2       1
2     cat3       2
3     cat1       3
```

the first column represents the category of products purchased by a customer. The the second represents the number associated with the purchase of the same Customer. So this Customer made 3 purchases.
I want to reshape the table in order to have all the combinations of the categories bought by this customer in first purchase then second and third purchase and a new columns that count the number of combination :

```
      1     2     3  count
0  cat1  cat3   NaN      1
1  cat2  cat3   NaN      1
2  cat1  cat3  cat1      1
3  cat2  cat3  cat1      1
```

I tried to pivot it like this :

```
df.pivot(columns='nb_achat', values='category')
```

but it did not work because of the combination. Do you have a way to do this ?

the goal is to know what a customer buys first time then second time and how many customers bought the same category in purchase 1 then 2 (for example)

EDIT :
here an exemple of the result

[result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO1XF.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "with all the possible combination of this columns"? Do you mean to have another row `4     NaN       3` in the example input?

Comment: sorry I am not following your logic here, can you please explain in more detail

Comment: this question requires more detail, 'all possible combinations' is not clear from your example

Comment: not really. In fact I have in the column category, the category of the purchased object and in the columns 'number' the purchased number. Example : in this df, the customer made 3 purchases. 2 item in the first, one item in the second and one item in the third purchase. I want a combination of the category of the item that his bought

Comment: I Added some details to my post, is it clearer?

Comment: sorry still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: sorry I tried to be clearer...I just add a picture of the result maybe if you forgot about the combinations thing and just try the reshape ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['cat1', 1], ['cat2', 1], ['cat3', 2],
               ['cat1', 3]], columns=['category',
              'number'])

from itertools import product
result_items = []
product_numbers = df.number.sort_values().unique()
product_numbers = product_numbers[product_numbers >= 2]

# get all the combinations of results for all the product numbers
for number in product_numbers:

    purchase_history = []
    for hist in range(1, number+1):
        purchase_history.append(df.category[df.number == hist].tolist())

    for item in product(*purchase_history):

        item_store = {}
        for i in range(1, number+1):
            item_store[i] = item[i-1]

        result_items.append(item_store)

# put them all into a dataframe
results = pd.DataFrame(result_items)
results.fillna(0, inplace=True)
# get the counts of all history
results = results.groupby(results.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')
# fix the NaN values
results.where(results!=0, np.nan, inplace=True)
print(results)
```

Results are:

```
      1     2     3  count
0  cat1  cat3   NaN      1
1  cat1  cat3  cat1      1
2  cat2  cat3   NaN      1
3  cat2  cat3  cat1      1
```

This `itertools` solution isn't particularly elegant. I'd love to see if someone can do this without that messy for loop!!

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly the result I wanted! It work great but not with a df of 5000 rows (MemoryError)...I'd love to see an other solution too  if anyone can do it haha. thanks again :)

Comment: Ya as those rows increase, it doesn't surprise me this gets a little heavy on memory. I am sure there is a better way to go about this though without having to go through that loop. Good luck